# How to place Indicators outside of Carousel Image?(Bootstrap 4)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to put bootstrap(4) indicators highlighted in red into the green area outside of the image. I've tried many things on this site already but none have worked so far, most likely because of the CSS rules I have. What can I do? Below is code which can be copy and pasted. Thank you in advance
[image]

```
 <div class="container-fluid px-0">

<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-8">
       <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide carousel-left" data-ride="carousel">
           <ol class="carousel-indicators indicator">
               <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
               <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
           
             <div class="carousel-inner ml-1">                    
               <div class="carousel-item active">
                 <img class="d-block vampire1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire" alt="First slide">
               </div>
                   
               <div class="carousel-item">
                 <img class="d-block vampire2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire" alt="Second slide">
               </div>                     
             </div>
            
     </div>
   </div>
```

Style:

```
    no-gutters {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .no-gutters > .col, .no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The carousel indicators use `position: absolute.` To move them below the images in the carousel, apply a negative value to the `ol` tag.

That will move the indicators over the content below the carousel, so be sure there’s a space for the indicators and that the indicator colors are compatible with whatever’s below the carousel.

It’s also helpful to have the images fit the available space, so I applied `img-fluid` to the images. The images should all be the same size.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -2.4375rem;
    }
    .carousel-indicators li {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="carouselControls" class="carousel slide carousel-left" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators indicator">
                    <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselControls" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class=" img-fluid vampire1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire" alt="First slide">
                    </div>

                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="img-fluid vampire2" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1280x720.png?text=vampire" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-12 bg-info">
            <p>Next section</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just realized my code wasn't running before because the order of my import tags were off as well. Thank you!